# jQuery issue when dynamically changing height jsFiddle

Tags: jquery

I wrote a bit of jquery to give equal height to multiple elements on the same page. It looks nice with content inside of boxes. It works on page load, but the problem is when the window is resized, the text within the box starts to overflow out of the box, instead of the boxes recalculating their necessary height.

Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/hV5AG/

Use your browser and resize it smaller horizontally to see what I'm talking about.

I tried adding:

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {
    equalHeight($(".equalheight"));
    });
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: You can also use CSS!

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for the help, but it does not appear that it is fixed. You just hid the overflow, but didn't address the issue with the box not being tall enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the boxes to auto before rechecking them

```
jQuery(function($) { 

    function equalHeight(group) {
        var tallest = 0;
        group.css('height','auto').each(function() {
            var thisHeight = parseInt($(this).css('height'), 10);
            if(thisHeight > tallest) {
                tallest = thisHeight;
            }
        });
        group.height(tallest);
    }
    equalHeight($(".equalheight"));

    $( window ).resize(function() {
        equalHeight($(".equalheight"));
    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hV5AG/28/)

Minified a little, it would look like this

```
function equalHeight(group) {
    group.css('height','auto').height(Math.max.apply(null, group.map(function(_,el) {
        return $(el).height();
    })));
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hV5AG/39/)

Comment: That looks great, thank you for the help! The only thing (which doesnt seem to exist in the fiddle) is that when I implement it on my site, the boxes are too tall on page load, but if I resize my browser, even for 1 pixel, to trigger the function, the box resizes to the proper height...?

Comment: It's exactly the same as it was, it just resets the height and checks it on resize? Did it work correctly before !

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set the height manually once, your `<div>`s aren't resizing automatically anymore. In your `equalHeight` function, reset the behavior to `'auto'` before you calculate the max height:

```
group.css('height','auto'); 
var tallest = 0;
group.each(function() {
   var thisHeight = $(this).height();
   if(thisHeight > tallest) {
      tallest = thisHeight;
   }
});
group.height(tallest);
```

Of course, you need to remember to call your function when the window is resized. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MGfMh/

Comment: See edit... you do, of course, need to call the function when the window resizes. Otherwise how would it know it needs to recalculate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
p {font-size: 2vw;}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hV5AG/34/)

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly. However,
>   when the value of overflow on the root element is auto, any scroll
>   bars are assumed not to exist. Note that the initial containing
>   block’s size is affected by the presence of scrollbars on the
>   viewport.

[Viewport-percentage lengths](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)